# requring unknown module "react-native-ios-charts" when trying to integrate a chart module within my react-native application

Tags: ios, react-native

I am new in react-native.
And I build my react-native application via cocoapods, and I did this work: npm install --save react-native-ios-charts or echarts-react or react-native-svg,and they show the same problem : requiring unknown module.Then how can I require the module through my code. Any help will be appreciated.

the code is here:

```
'use strict'

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Navbar,
} =React;
var chart = require('react-native-ios-charts');

class Chart extends Component {

render() {
  return (
     <Text>hi</Text >
);
}
  }

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 30,
    paddingBottom: 30
  },
  navText: {
   fontSize: 16
  },
  right: {
    opacity: 0
  },
  list: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 0
  },
  listItem: {
    padding: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2)'
  },
  description: {
    marginTop: 5,
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.7)'
  }
});

module.exports = Chart;
```

[`requiring unknown module`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebWXE.png)

Comment: check following:
1. make sure your module shows up under node_modules folder.
2. you may need to restart the script engine after installing new module

Comment: I have tried the 2 steps several times but still not work

Comment: Also check your `package.json` file. Does it show `react-native-ios-charts`?  Also close all of your terminal window, and Xcode and retry to ensure the NPM server has picked up the new node modules you installed.

Comment: I got the same issue, did you solve it?